# Finding control on pages that inherits from base page

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance

In my project all of the .aspx pages inherit from a custom base class page which in turn inherits from System.Web.UI.Page.
I want to find the controls in current page. for that one I am using
foreach loop

```
foreach(control c in page.controls)
```

for this I am unable to cast my current page to system.web.ui.page.
how to cast the current page to system system.web.ui.page?

Comment: You can do like ((System.Web.UI.Page)this.Page).Controls. What is your issue? Have you face any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that you are dealing with a control-tree, so you might want to have a recursion here. Following method should help (Linq with a recursive call):

```
private static IEnumerable<Control> FlattenControlTree<TFilterType>(Control control)
{
    if (control is TFilterType)
    {
        yield return control;
    }
    foreach (Control contr in control.Controls.Cast<Control>().SelectMany((c) => FlattenControlTree<TFilterType>(c)))
    {
        if (contr is TFilterType)
        {
            yield return contr;
        }
    }
}
```

By the end of the day, you only need to call:

```
var controls = FlattenControlTree<YourBaseType>(this.Page);
```

Please note that this kind of recursion is not very effective when it comes to big trees.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this;

foreach(Control c in ((System.Web.UI.Page)this.Page).Controls)